# Reading least significant bits in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, syslog

I am having to parse the Facility and Severity of syslog messages in Python.  These values come with each message as a single integer.  The severity of the event is 0-7, specified in the 3 least significant bits in the integer.  What is the easiest/fastest way to evaluate these 3 bits from the number?

The code I have right now just does a 3 bit right shift, than multiplies that number times 8, and subtracts the result from the original.

```
FAC = (int(PRI) >> 3)
SEV = PRI - (FAC * 8)
```

There must be a less convoluted way to do this- rather than wiping out the bits, and subtracting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SEV = PRI & 7
FAC = PRI >> 3
```

Like that.

Answer (score 4):

Just apply a bit mask:

```
sev = int(pri) & 0x07
```

(0x07 is 00000111)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
result = FAC & 0x7
```

Comment: In Python 3 (and perhaps in 2.6/2.7?), you can even use a binary literal making it *very* obvious to those having trouble memorizing (powers of two) - 1: `0b111`.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to extract the least significant bits would be to do a bitwise AND with the appropriate mask (7 in this case)